# Displaying the binomial coefficient symbol in math mode

Tags: math-mode, symbols

The problem is caused by the symbol of binomial coefficient (symbol of Newton), often used in math:

```
{N}\choose{k}
```

In my document I have formula:

```
$$ P(A) = \sum P(\{ (e_1,...,e_N) \})  =  {N}\choose{k} \cdot p^kq^{N-k}$$
```

which is rendered as:

[image]

but should be:

[image]

Comment: Are you using LaTeX or plain TeX?

Comment: I am compiling pdfs from files by pdflatex.

Comment: Is the symbol `N` really supposed to represent the physical unit for force (in which case you should render it in an upright rather than italic style), or are you using the symbol to denote an integer?

Comment: I mean that I've cited the formula which is correct but pdflatex generate something which I don't want. I'm sorry, but I translated binomial coefficient directly from Polish. Sorry for misrepresentation.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

To fix this, simply add a pair of braces around the whole binomial coefficient, i.e.

```
{N\choose k}
```

(The braces around `N` and `k` are not needed.)

However, as you're using LaTeX, it is better to use `\binom` from `amsmath`, i.e.

```
\binom{N}{k}
```

Further, it is not recommended to use `$$ ... $$`, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) Last, I'll note that `amsmath` provides different commands for 'continuation dots', including `\dotsc` for triple dots between commas.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
 P(A) = \sum P(\{ (e_1,\dotsc,e_N) \})  =  \binom{N}{k} \cdot p^kq^{N-k}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What differs between \dots and \dotsc, with overleaf.com, the outputs are identical.

Comment: @pzorba75 The output of `\dots` depends on what it is placed between, try for example `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{amsmath} \begin{document} $1,\dots,n$ $1+\dots+n$ \end{document}`. Read also section 4.3 in the `amsmath` manual.

Answer (score 11):

Just add curly braces around it to separate it:

```
$$ P(A) = \sum P(\{ (e_1,...,e_N) \})  =  {{N}\choose{k}} \cdot p^kq^{N-k}$$
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Hello @Lance Everhart! `$$ ... $$` is obsolet. Use `\[ ... \] ` see [l2tabu](https://ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu-english) on page 6.

Comment: Isn’t this exactly the same as the first line of the other answer?

Comment: Hello @GuM! No. Before the braces `{` and `}` weren't escaped by the slash sign.

Comment: I beg your pardon, escaped by what?

Comment: Hello @GuM! Maybe escaped isn't the correct word here. My english isn't well. If you wish to use `{` or `}` as a text sign, you should type `\{` and `\}`. I meant the braces before and after `(e_1,...,e_N)`. I hope it's now clear.

Comment: @Su-47: I don’t want to seem obstinate, but the braces around `(e_1,...,e_N)` are correctly indicated as `\{` and `\}` in the existing answer too…

Comment: @GuM `{{N}\choose{k}}` is the difference.

Comment: @Su-47 `$$...$$` is not obsolete, is TeX (and it should not be used in a LaTeX document, where you should use `\[...\]`).

Comment: @CarLaTeX: What’s the difference between `{N\choose k}` and `{{N}\choose{k}}` in this context?

Comment: @GuM Nothing, but I think that is the difference the OP was pointing out...

Comment: "{{N}\choose{k}}" instead of "{N}\choose{k}" binds the \choose operation to only what is in the outer braces instead of doing it over everything on the left side to everything on the right side of \choose, try the difference out and it works fine

Comment: @GuM: Ah sorry, its been fixed. I think it erased the slashes on them when I wrote my answer, those weren't meant to be removed, it was the extra braces around the {N}\choose{K} that was only meant to be different.

Comment: @LanceEverhart: I know how `\choose` works, I was just saying that your answer adds nothing to the other one, that was posted five years ago.  I hate to sound that harsh, but the policy of this site is to ask users to avoid such duplicates.

Comment: @GuM I see what you are saying now. Sorry about that, I missed where the other person said {N\choose k}.

Comment: Hello @GuM! At the time I wrote my comment the braces `{` and `}` around `(e_1,...,e_N)` hadn't the backslash sign in front of each. In this time Werner corrected it, [see](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/423543/revisions). This is what I'm writing about. I hope it's now clear. In my [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127707/displaying-the-binomial-coefficient-symbol-in-math-mode/423543?noredirect=1#comment1059600_423543) above is an typo: I wrote slash sign and meaning backslash sign.