# How to put one symbol (number) above another

Tags: superscripts

I'd like to put one symbol over another? There are some similar things in math, like `$\binom{a}{b}$`, but I don't want the parentheses, or `$\frac{a}{b}$` without the division line.  The closest I've found is `$\overset{a}{b}$` (from `mathtools`) but the `a` ends up smaller than the `b`.

Comment: Use `$\overset{\displaystyle a}{b}$`

Comment: I came upon this question looking for the notation of the binomial coefficient, which is similar to OP's request although wrapped in parentheses. If found the answer to my question over here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127711/137054

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does it serves for the purpose?

```
$_{b}^{a}$
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 10):

Just to give the OP different options, here I show the basic features of the `stackengine` approach to stacking, with the first column as a `\stackon`, the second as a `\stackunder` and the third as a `\stackanchor`.  The first row uses "short" stacks, in which the gap between the top of one element and the bottom of the element above it are fixed, whereas the second row uses "long" stacks, in which the baseline skip between adjacent rows is fixed.

While I don't show it here, the default gaps and baseline skips may be redefined, or simply passed as an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
% \def\stacktype{S}% DEFAULT TYPE, constant gap between stacked elements
\[
x \stackon{g}{b} y \stackon{b}{g} z\quad
x \stackunder{g}{b} y \stackunder{b}{g} z\quad
x \stackanchor{g}{b} y \stackanchor{b}{g} z
\]
\def\stacktype{L}% constant baselineskip between stacked elements
\[
x \stackon{g}{b} y \stackon{b}{g} z\quad
x \stackunder{g}{b} y \stackunder{b}{g} z\quad
x \stackanchor{g}{b} y \stackanchor{b}{g} z\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As a customization, I found an optional [gap] parameter after the `\stackon`, `\stackunder` or `\stackanchor` commands. _E.g._ I used `\newcommand{\lgeq}{\stackon[2pt]{\stackunder[0pt]{=}{<}}{>}}` to get something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/j8vSSje.png). Of course that was in `math` mode-- using `\stackMath` after loading the package `stackengine`.

Comment: @ParthaD. Nice.  That package developer thought of everything! `;^)`

Answer (score 9):

If you can cope with a bit of plain TeX syntax, you can just do this.

```
Put $a$ over $b$: $a \atop b$
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
${b}^{\#}$

$\overset{\#}{b}$
```

For `overset`, you need `amsmath` package.

[image]

Comment: A little short. Package `amsmath` is needed for `\overset` and `#` will not work out of the box, use `\#` instead.

Comment: `overset` is explicitly not what OP want because the 2 symbols size are not equal though.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `stackrel`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Look at this: $\stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow}$

This is one way of how to put one symbol above another symbol.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! It would be nice if you could extend the code into a small, complete example that can compile so future readers can copy and paste your solution as it is, i.e. your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please , helps improve the site :)

Comment: Just like `overset`, this is not what OP want because the 2 symbols size are not equal. This would be an appropriate answer for [syntax - How do I put text over symbols? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74125/how-do-i-put-text-over-symbols/74128#74128)... but the top answer there already mention `stackrel`.