# How to put a symbol above another

Tags: math-mode, symbols, subscripts, superscripts

Following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240758/how-to-put-one-symbol-number-above-another), I'm having problems when using the accepted answer on subscripts.

```
\[ 
A_  {z {_{y}^{x}} {_{x}^{y}} } \qquad
    {z {_{y}^{x}} {_{x}^{y}} }
\]
```

I don't know why, when in a subscript, the alignement/centering messes up.

I've also tried other options. I'll comment them a bit.

- \atop , \genfrac and \above

```
\[
A_  {z {x \atop y} {y \atop x} } \qquad
    {z {x \atop y} {y \atop x} }
\]
\[ 
A_  {z {\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{2}{x}{y}} {\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{2}{y}{x}} } \qquad
    {z {\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{2}{x}{y}} {\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{2}{y}{x}} }
\]
\[
A_  {z {x \above 0pt y} {y \above 0pt x} } \qquad
    {z {x \above 0pt y} {y \above 0pt x} }
\]
```

They seem to render exactly the same. They have too much blank space.

- \stackanchor from "stackengine" package

```
\stackMath
\[
A_  {z {\stackanchor{x}{y}} {\stackanchor{y}{x}} } \qquad
    {z {\stackanchor{x}{y}} {\stackanchor{y}{x}} }
\]
```

In both cases, it's misaligned. In the subscript, it's not the right size,

- \overset from "mathtools" package and \stackrel

```
\[
A_  {z {\overset{x}{y}} {\overset{y}{x}} } \qquad
    {z {\overset{x}{y}} {\overset{y}{x}} }
\]
\[
A_  {z {\stackrel{x}{y}} {\stackrel{y}{x}} } \qquad
    {z {\stackrel{x}{y}} {\stackrel{y}{x}} }
\]
```

They seem to render exactly the same. In both cases, not centered, neither the correct size.

By "aligned" I mean "$xy$ alignment", so "misaligned" refers to anything else.
There's no need that it renders strictly perfect aligned, centered or sized: something close will do.

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: do you want something like this?      \[ A_{z_{y^{x}}^{x^{y}}} \qquad z_{y^{x}}^{x^{y}} \]

Comment: @EdsonMarcon, thanks, but no. I added an image to clarify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want to stack the objects? In this case a version of `\atop` can do it (using `\genfrac`, of course). The trick is to force `\textstyle` when the object is found in `\displaystyle`, otherwise the standard action is good.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\stk}[2]{\mathinner{\!\mathpalette\stk@{{#1}{#2}}\!}}
\newcommand{\stk@}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{1}}%
  {\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}}%
  #2%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
A_{z\stk{x}{y}\stk{y}{x}} \qquad
z\stk{x}{y}\stk{y}{x}\ne z_{xy}^{yx} \qquad
z\stk{aa}{b}\stk{b}{aa}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This will do.

Answer (score 9):

Something like this? (Observe: no need for `\overset`, `\stackanchor`, `\atop`, etc.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\complicatedz{z_{yx}^{xy}}
\begin{document}
\[
\complicatedz \quad A_{\complicatedz} \quad A_{\complicatedz}^{}
\]
\end{document}
```

The two `A_{...}` terms differ, very slightly, in the vertical positioning of the subscript term -- which I've called, not very imaginatively, `\zcomplicated`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't believe I haven't thought of such simple approach. It renders perfectly for this cases. However, I apologize for not being clear enough on my purposes: both _x^y and _y^x are different objects. Therefore, I could use something like egreg's third example or having a z in between the x, y.