# Combinatorial notation (\choose) not working with \frac

Tags: equations, amsmath, fractions

I want to display the following

```
$p_N= \frac{{200 \choose 11}{ 200 \choose {N-189}}}{200 \choose N}$
```

However, texmaker gives me this error:

[image]

Does anybody know why is that? I have tried replacing the combinatorial expressions with random letters or numbers such as

```
$p_N= \frac{{123}{ yellow {green}}}{pink}$
```

and it works. Does  anybody know how to fix it so it works with combinatorials as well?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is one of the reasons why using the `\choose` method is not the best.

What happens? When `\frac` is expanded, it looks for two arguments, which in your case are determined to be

```
{200 \choose 11}{ 200 \choose {N-189}}
```

and

```
200 \choose N
```

Then TeX will transform this into the primitive call

```
{\begingroup<first argument>\endgroup\over<second argument>}
```

which in your case is

```
{\begingroup{200 \choose 11}{ 200 \choose {N-189}}\endgroup\over 200 \choose N}
```

which is indeed ambiguous as the error message says: it's like

```
a \over b \over c
```

which is of course invalid.

Do yourself a favor and use

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$p_N=\frac{\binom{200}{11} \binom{200}{N-189}}{\binom{200}{N}}$

\end{document}
```

which is clearer and doesn't require extra braces like

```
$p_N= \frac{{200 \choose 11}{ 200 \choose {N-189}}}{{200 \choose N}}$
```

By the way, the braces around `N-189` are redundant. But, really, use the `amsmath` method that automatically supplies the internal braces when expanding things to the primitive calls.

Answer (score 8):

I have seen often `\choose` in MathJaX and if I not remember not good also in Open Office or LibreOffice. For my humble opinion are important to have a full minimal working example to see the mistakes. I use often `$\binom{n}{k}$.`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,xcolor}


\begin{document}
\[p_N= \frac{\binom{200}{11}\binom{200}{N}}{\binom{200}{N-189}}\]
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am aiming for having two combinatorials on the top and one on the bottom. Nevertheless, this works. Why do you think it doesn't work with \choose ?

Comment: @KanyeWest I have put as package `xcolor`, but I have not understood the question of the colors. Sorry.

Comment: No worries! All good. I will just use \binom from now on as it doesn't seem to have the same issues.

Comment: @KanyeWest See this old question. All the best. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127707/displaying-the-binomial-coefficient-symbol-in-math-mode. After can you give, please, to the user **egreg** the green check mark? My explanation is very poor. Thank you very much for this favour.

Comment: No worries, I should be thank you for the effort that you put in my issue.